# pgfplots: change vertical position of node label in addplot

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, labels

In the MWE below, how can I change the vertical position of the `label` associated with the curve? For example, if I wanted to put it below the curve?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} []

    \addplot[
        domain=10:400,
        samples=100,
    ] { sqrt(x)}
    node[pos=0.97,label={$f(x)$}] {}
    ;

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `label=below:{$f(x)$}` as usual. All the position specifiers like `right`, `left` `below left` etc will work. Also, since `label` is a node, you can pass other options to it too like

```
label={[text=red]below:{$f(x)$}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} []

    \addplot[
        domain=10:400,
        samples=100,
    ] { sqrt(x)}
    node[pos=0.97,label=below:{$f(x)$}] {}
    ;

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. And I see I can also fine-tune the vertical spacing with, e.g., `label={[label distance=4pt]below:{$f(x)$}}`.